# Flutter VScode Save to auto Restart

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have no idea why after changing my stuff and do hot reload, it does not apply the changes (if I do a restart, then it does). And, wondering if there is a way to `Restart` the app right after I save the file.

I've tried with `Run` -> `Start with Debugging/ Start without Debugging`.

Still, does not restart nor hot reload the app after I save the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just delete your VS cache folder and VS temp folder.

> Press windows button and type:
>
> > `%temp%`
>
> > `%appdata%`

2. Check your launch.json in .vscode folder. delete and recreate if necessary.